# BCP IN error : [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

Tags: csv, bcp

BCP IN issue in SQL server 2008.

Trying to BCP in from .CSV to sql server 2008 table using batch script.

Not using any format file but used the delimiter pipe.

And also .CSV file consists of comma seperator when opened in the notepad++

Getting the below error:

```
BCP Output: 
Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1
```

Comment: This is not a bug report site. Could you make this more a question, please?

Comment: This error usually means not all the rows in your .csv file have the same number of fields. We will need more information from you for a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, BTW, i was getting frustrated with the same issue today. Turns out the format file had a prefix length specifier that had a value of 2 (auto prompted during format file generation - why?) for field two which was a varchar field. Once I made it to field length specifier to 0, file started working.

PS: my file was tab separated.